# How to find the longest line through the center of mass of the contour?

Tags: python, opencv, math, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to know how to draw the longest line that passes through the centroid of a polygon made up of contour points.

**workflow of my algorithm:**

1. Read a binary image in opencv grayscale.
2. Use the python opencv findContours function to find the boundary points of the object and the centroid of these boundary points.
3. Draw the longest line that can be drawn inside the polygon and passes through the centroid.

I imagine it would work by drawing a line, like in fig1, that passes through the centroid and meets the boundary of the polygon, and then rotating this line gradually to find the longest one. However, I can't think of how to implement this in python :(
[image: fig1]

**example what I want image:**
[image: fig2]

Is there a good method to draw the longest line that passes through the centroid of a polygon and can be drawn within the polygon?

**What I'm tried befor:**

**updated**

1.Load the image and form contours.

2.Calculate the centroid of the contour points.

3.Create vectors connecting the centroid to each contour point.

4.Calculate the average vector (primary orientation) of all vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load image.
binary_img = cv2.imread(f'C:/Users/MSDL-DESK-02/Documents/result1/6.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Find contour.
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = contours[0]

# Find centroid point.
M = cv2.moments(contour)
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# Calculate vectors
vectors = contour - [cx, cy]
print(vectors)
# Find orientation.
mean_vector = np.mean(vectors, axis=0)
print('mean vector란??',mean_vector)
# Visualize result.
scale_factor = 30

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(binary_img, cmap='gray')
plt.scatter([cx], [cy], color='red', s=10, label='Center')
plt.quiver(cx, cy, mean_vector[0,0], mean_vector[0,1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1/scale_factor, color='blue', label='Orientation',width=0.002)
plt.axis('off')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Main Orientation of the Object')
plt.show()
```

**sample Image:**
[image]

**Inference result:**
[image]

However, it failed.

Comment: I think you can just plot the points and draw a line between them… but I don’t know.

Comment: does it have to be the centroid? the line connecting the two most distant points may not  go through the centroid at all

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The line drawn inside the polygon doesn't necessarily have to connect the two farthest points. The key is to find the longest line that passes through the centroid.

Comment: It seems to me that an exhaustive n^2 search is not necessary. You should be able to draw a line through each contour point and the centroid, then check to see where each one exits the polygon on the other side. For large polygons this should be cheaper.

Comment: Would the major axis from `cv.fitEllipse()` work? See Section 5: Orientation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html).

Comment: this seems related but not equivalent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feret_diameter

Comment: opencv has a point-polygon intersection/test but no line-polygon intersection/test. you may want to write such a thing as a utility function. makes the code clearer. -- contour-line intersection is just line-line intersection applied to all the line segments, but that would cost O(n^2). to avoid O(n^2), putting the contour into a smarter structure (tree indexing on angle, or points sorted by angle around centroid) may be... smart... er.

Comment: Consider a crescent-moon-like shape. The centroid doesn't have to be inside the polygon. Can the line cross the contour to connect on the other side or must it stop as soon as it hits the contour?

Comment: @SimonGoater oh, the line can cross the contour to connect on the other side sir.